# Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to int

Tags: java, arraylist, integer, addition

I am have a little problem with small part of my code: it says

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to int.

Can someone please help me out? My code is below:

```
ArrayList<Integer> tower = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int Kilo = tower.add(1);
int Jan tower.add(2);
```

Comment: What do you think that code should do? Why do you think so?

Comment: @Henry: What does `add` return?

Comment: Making the value of kilo = the value of tower 1 and making the value of jan = value of tower 2. Sorry I have not touched on java and this is one bit of sorry from my old project and because of this error my project is not running. I am not really sure.

Comment: adds the values to arraylist?

Comment: What does `ArrayList#add` do?

Comment: add values to arraylist

Comment: And what does `int Kilo = tower.add(1);` do? (This is a trick question.)

Comment: What I am trying to do is, add the value 1 to the arraylist tower which then get put in variable kilo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand from the code you provide, you need to use `tower.get(1)` etc. and not `tower.add(1)` etc.

Comment: Thanks, figured it out that was what I was looking for. Programming can be such a nightmare.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with `int Kilo = tower.add(1);`.  The `add` method returns a Boolean, which most people don't bother storing, because it always returns true.  This is because the superclass of ArrayList, Collection, uses that boolean to say whether or not the collection was changed as a result (with ArrayList, it's always changed, but other collections may not have that be true).  You're trying to store this boolean value into an `int` named 'Kilo', hence the problem.

Based on what you've said, I think you want the following:

```
tower.add(1); //Adds 1 to the ArrayList
int Kilo = 1; //Stores 1 into Kilo
```

Comment: I thought that to add values onto a arraylist we need to use add method

Comment: You are using the add method.  The problem is you want to call it without the `int Kilo =` part.  `tower.add(1);` is all you need.  If you want to store the value into a variable called 'Kilo' as well, you'd need to have that be a separate statement.

Comment: The trick is in understanding that `int Kilo = tower.add(1)` then turns into `int Kilo = true`, which isn't valid.

Comment: How can i add the value 1 to the arraylist - tower and then put this value in kilo

Comment: See my edited response.  They're two separate things.

Comment: thanks, figured out what the problem was, it turned out to be easily. I couldn't get my head around it. Programming can be 1 hell of a nightware sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do the `tower.add(1);` and the `tower.add(2);`, unless you are also attempting to cast variables to the contents of the ArrayList. 
Just use: 

`tower.add(1); //Adds 1 to the ArrayList
tower.add(2); //Adds 2 to the ArrayList`